# Is it possible to compile and run sample projects from the Apple developer library without using a GUI?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, terminal, compilation

I want to compile and run [this application](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) without using the Xcode GUI. Is this possible? I have so far only been successful with this baby step:

```
clang -framework AppKit main.m; ./a.out
```

But I need to compile and run the whole app, not just `main.m`.

Answer (score 0):

Running `xcodebuild` will build the first Xcode project found in the current directory, using default settings. (If this isn't quite what you want, `xcodebuild --help` for more options.)